# Tomcat, JAX-RS, Jersey, @PathParam: how to pass dots and slashes?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, slash

Having a method like this:

```
@GET @Path("/name/{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getProperty(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
}
```

How do I pass a value like "test./test"?

```
/name/test./test     gives HTTP 404
/name/test.%2Ftest   gives HTTP 400
/name/test.%252Ftest prints test%2Ftest
```

But if I do `name = URLDecoder.decode(name);` it prints `/test` and the first part of `test.` disappears.

There is one or two questions like this already but they are old and there was no good solution found, I thought I'll ask again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The pattern in the `@Path` annotation is internally turned into a regular expression, with the template parts matching only selected characters by default. In particular, they normally *don't* match `/` characters; that's almost always the right thing to do (as it lets you put templates part way through a path) but in this case it isn't as you're wanting to consume the *whole* subsequent path. To get everything, we have to override the regular expression fragment for that particular template; this is actually pretty easy, since we just put in the template fragment a `:` followed by the RE that we want to use:

```java
@GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/name/{name:.+}")
public String getProperty(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return name;
}
```

This will match all characters after the `/name/` (up to but not including any `?` query part) but will only match if there's something there at all. Be aware that if you have any other `@Path("/name/...")` things about, things can get really confusing! So don't do that.

Comment: Works! Can pass any number of slashes, all get captured just fine. Will this work with all JAX-RS implementations or it's how jersey works? Either way, thanks a lot, it solved my problem.

Comment: @Maxim I think it's standard, and I use it with Apache CXF.

Comment: Looks nice, but it seems that back slashes are not matched by this regular expression..

Answer (score 6):

If you using tomcat, and want pass `/` in pathparam. besides the `@Path("/name/{name:.+}")` stuff as 'Donal Fellows' said, you should add `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true` to your jvm arguments, see also [tomcat security-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html).

Comment: I don't need that as long as the path really contains a `/`, and not an encoded one.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the encoding type, the following works for me with `/name/test.%252Ftest`:

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8"));
return URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Works! Added encoding and it turns "test.%252Ftest" to "test./test", not just "/test". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish v4 accept encoded scape for slash %2f. Then we can pass the encoded String test.%2Ftest and get the result test./test using URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8"). I think this is a better solution especially when you have many params in one request. Using the path @Path("/name/{name:.+}") is great solution when we have few parameters in a request.

Using %252f complicates the client request becouse are needed to contruct the encoding request String manually. With glassfish v4 it's easy to use percent encoding with URLEncoder.encode in client and URLDecoder.decode in server to wished Strings. The most programing languages has percent encoding and decoding, therefore it's perfect solution.

I tried enable encoded slash in glassfish v3 but no success, here is the sintaxe I tried used

bin\asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.encoded-slash-enabled=true configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.encoded-slash-enabled=true

Command set executed successfully.

Regards
Cassio Seffrin