# Jersey accepting encoded path param values

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

We' re trying to consume the below url :

http://localhost:9006/test/adsystem-local.bw.bw2hana.query.zso_cp01%2FZSO_CP01_Q0001

where  we are passing encoded path params since this param contains slases along with the special chars 
as

```
{ObjectName}=adsystem-local.bw.bw2hana.query.zso_cp01%2FZSO_CP01_Q0001
```

But we are getting

> Bad request(400 status code)

as response.

I tried seraching on netl ,but jersey is not recognizing the changes which were made as per the instructions which were given in the below url.I am still getting 400 status code.

[Tomcat, JAX-RS, Jersey, @PathParam: how to pass dots and slashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130793/tomcat-jax-rs-jersey-pathparam-how-to-pass-dots-and-slashes)

Comment: encode your url from client and decode on server?

Comment: we passed the encoded url as posted but jersey is not able to recognize it.

Comment: encode just the parameters?

Comment: system-local.bw.bw2hana.query.zso_cp01/ZSO_CP01_Q0001.This is our param .And encoded param is below  adsystem-local.bw.bw2hana.query.zso_cp01%2FZSO_CP01_Q0001

Comment: I have the same: Tomcat 8, Jersey 2.25.1, only the parameter is encoded with URLEncoder, breakpoint in my resource class is not reached, the framework somehow returns Bad request (400)